# Getting syntax error in sql select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, syntax-error

I have this sql statement:

```
SELECT inquiry_response, 
        inquiry_response_date, 
        date_initiated, 
        date_closed, 
        (select count(*) 
            from Inquiry_Responses 
            where InquiryID = 1 AND lawyerID = 1) as col1 
        (select count(*) 
            from Lawyers, Firms, Conflicts, Inquiries, Inquiry_Responses 
            where Conflicts.lawyerID=Lawyers.lawyerID and 
                Inquiry_Responses.lawyerID=Lawyers.lawyerID and 
                Inquiry_Responses.InquiryID=Inquiries.InquiryID and 
                Conflicts.firmID=Firms.firmID and 
                Conflicts.firmID IN 
                (select FirmID 
                    from WorkPeriod 
                    where InquiryID = 1) and 
                Inquiry_Responses.lawyerID= 1 and 
                Inquiries.InquiryID = 1 and 
                date_created between date_initiated and inquiry_response_date) as col2
from Inquiry_Responses, Inquiries 
WHERE Inquiries.InquiryID = Inquiry_Responses.InquiryID AND Inquiry_Responses.InquiryID = 1 AND lawyerID = 1
```

and I am getting a syntax error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

**Note: The 1 values are actually parameter variables, but I will fill that in later.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a comma here:

```
(select count(*) 
            from Inquiry_Responses 
            where InquiryID = 1 AND lawyerID = 1) as col1,
                                                         ^ Here!
```

Comment: oh right, I missed that, thanks.

Comment: No worries, that's why they pay me the big money